# Programmatically clipping a note into Evernote (from a URL)

Tags: python, evernote

Using is it possible to add a URL to Evernote programmatically?

I am using the Python API, and am able to create notes by manually adding   XML content to a note object.

If I want to add a note from a URL, I'm wondering if I need to fetch the URL myself and convert the HTML into Evernote's XML note format manually, or if a clipping API or service exists, which would allow me to just provide a source URL for the article I want clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as for now, there is no clipping service available.
You have to fetch the HTML content and convert it to ENML by hand. 
The process can be tedious as HTML can be malformed and you need to inline css...
I usually use http://diffbot.com or http://embed.ly to extract the 'useful content' on the pages I want to clip.